# Cucumber executable jar has undefined scenarios

Tags: jar, cucumber, build.gradle, cucumber-jvm, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I try to create an executable jar for my cucumber kotlin application but it prints in log that all scenarios are undefined:

```
...
3 Scenarios (3 undefined)
8 Steps (5 skipped, 3 undefined)
...
```

The application **can be executed correctly** from command line or from IntelliJ

Entry point of program:

```
package dsdms.client
import io.cucumber.core.cli.Main

class Main{
    companion object{
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            Main.main("-p", "pretty",
                "--glue", "dsdms.client.cucumber",
                "--plugin", "html:build/reports/cucumber",
                "classpath:features")
            println("Hello Worldddd2!")

        }
    }
}
```

For project building I use Gradle with kotlin DSL

I tried to use first `src/test` and then `src/main`  folders but even if I can execute all correctly form console it doesn't work for the jar execution

For fat jar generation I use:

```
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "dsdms.client.Main"
    }

    dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    from({
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
    })

    destinationDirectory.set(file("$buildDir/output"))
}
```

Jar file from inside seems to have all files needed for execution
[screenshot of jar file in zip format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1uKV.png)

[Gradle module structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s90zd.png)

[Here link to repository that reproduce my problem](https://github.com/DenGuzawr22/Executable-cucumber-jar-error-example). It also contains a jar file produced by project

Comment: So what does your project look like? And what does the jar file look like? Please don't include those in your posts if they're too big, make your project smaller first.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje add two screenshots with project and jar structure

Comment: Bit hard to say. The contents of the jar file is probably not correct. For example I don't see anything to merge the files in META-INF and the module info, if copied from another jar, might also be creating problems.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje add link to the repo that reproduce the problem and contains the problematic jar file

Comment: That's helpful, but you've got quite a bit going on in your project. Try to make it smaller first so you can isolate the problem.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje I found out that some dependencies and code were not used in the project I removed all of them. It seems to be almost the minimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating your jar file you've set `duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE` so any duplicate files will get ignored.

If you set:

```
duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.WARN
```

You'll see that:

```
> Task :SystemTester:jar
Encountered duplicate path "META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class" during copy operation configured with DuplicatesStrategy.WARN
Encountered duplicate path "META-INF/services/io.cucumber.core.backend.BackendProviderService" during copy operation configured with DuplicatesStrategy.WARN
Encountered duplicate path "META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class" during copy operation configured with DuplicatesStrategy.WARN
Encountered duplicate path "META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class" during copy operation configured with DuplicatesStrategy.WARN
```

And these warnings matter! To understand why it is important to understand what these files do. So it would be worth reading the [JAR File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jar/jar.html).

But in short for your problem, this is the warning that matters:

```
Encountered duplicate path "META-INF/services/io.cucumber.core.backend.BackendProviderService" during copy operation configured with DuplicatesStrategy.WARN
```

Because if you look at your dependencies you can see that you've got:

```ini
[libraries]
cucumber-java = {module = "io.cucumber:cucumber-java",  version.ref="cucumber"}
...
cucumber-java8 = {module = "io.cucumber:cucumber-java8",  version.ref="cucumber"}
```

Both of which include the `META-INF/services/io.cucumber.core.backend.BackendProviderService` file.

For `cucumber-java` this file contains:

```
io.cucumber.java.JavaBackendProviderService
```

While for `cucumber-java8` it contains:

```
io.cucumber.java8.Java8BackendProviderService
```

These tell Cucumber what which services it has available to detect step definitions (i.e. it lets Cucumber know you using annotations or lambdas)`.

Now if you unzip the jar file you've made (you can do this using your favorite zip application) you'll find it only contains the `BackendProviderService` registration for `cucumber-java` and not the one for `cucumber-java8`. As such your step definitions are not loaded because Cucumber doesn't it understands lambda step definitions.

The quick, and wrong way, to fix this would be to remove `cucumber-java` as a dependency. But you may run into other problems of a similar nature. So your best option would be to expand your Gradle task to merge `META-INF/services` files.

How? Not a clue. I don't use Gradle.